# Copy between 10.9 host and guest in Parallels

Tags: virtualization, parallels-desktop

I have been using Parallels 9 no problem for quite a while for .Net development in Windows. I have recently changed over to working on OS X applications, and as such, I am using Xamarin.Mac.

As a part of our dev cycle, we have to test. In doing this, I spun up a Mavericks VM, and installed Parallels Tools, updates and created a "Clean Slate" snapshot.

The only problem is I can't get files to and from the VM at all.

The first method I tried was the usual old <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> options to no avail, getting the following response;

[image]

In addition to this, I mounted my local home directory (enabled by default) and tried to copy the item over. I could browse the directory fine, but on copy, I got the following information;

[image]

Is there some sort of incompatibility with copying between an OSX host and its OSX guest?

Comment: In you Windows virtual machine, go to File Manager and open Computer > (network drives) Host or Computer > (network drives) Home. These should take you to your Mac HD and Home folder respectively. You can copy between the folders.

Comment: Although I do have a Windows VM in use, the issue is between an OSX virtual machine (guest) and an OSX host (my main working platform)

Comment: Why exactly would you want to use a Mac VM on a Mac?

Comment: Disposable default test environment. We develop an OSX application as a part of our service, and want to have a disposable VM to spin up to capture the entire installation and usage process. In addition to this, We are considering using the VM's to allow more than one developer to use OSX at a time, via remote desktop if they don't own a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

you have to update your parallels tools, to do so as i remember you have to select Window install parallels tools, then follow the on screen instructions

Comment: My Parallels is up to date, and I have repeatedly tried installing tools (even tried a VM disposal, and starting anew) and that didn't do anything.